# Undefined reference to CreateCompatibleDC, BitBlt, etc.?

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

I already linked to gdi32.lib. In desperation, I also linked to two different versions of gdi32.lib, as well as gdiplus.lib, and included all the gdi headers I could find, to no avail. However, this problem began before the extra links, so I think I can safely assume my problem isn't collisions between libraries or any sort of interference like that.

Inclusions/definitions:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include "UVMap.h"
```

Related code:

```
case WM_PAINT:{
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        BITMAP bmp = screen.getBitmap(hdcMemory);
        BitBlt(hdc,0,0,w,h,hdcMemory,0,0,SRCCOPY);
        EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
        DeleteDC(hdc);
    }break;
```

Every result I found when searching for this problem claimed that you just had to link to gdi32. Here are the links I added:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64\Gdi32.Lib
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\Gdi32.Lib
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\GdiPlus.lib

Edit: the errors appear like this:

```
.../Testing.cpp:50: undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'
.../Testing.cpp:52: undefined reference to `BitBlt@36'
```

Like that? I did the linking in Eclipse, via Project > Properties > Path Variables. There are no entries under the Linked Resources tab, nor does it appear editable.

Comment: Don't hard code the paths for the libs.  As long as your search paths are set correctly (should be done when you install Visual Studio) you only need to specify the name of the lib, that's it.  Or you could prefer to set it in code, #pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib").  The version of Windows you're setting seems correct, Windows 2000, and Windows.h should include the necessary header.  The only thing I can guess, are you sure you're linking correctly?

Comment: It is not even clear whether you have a linking problem. Show a representative error message or three, and explain exactly how you did the linking.

Comment: I tried to add it to this comment; see the edit above.

Comment: It would probably help if you also included your linking command that's actually used to link the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link to [coredll.lib for `CreateCompatibleDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx).

You need to link to for [Gdi32.lib for `BitBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For reference, when you get a link error involving a Windows function, just google the function and go to the MSDN documentation for that function (I've linked to the two pages for these two specific functions), and then scroll down to the Requirements section and make sure you're linking to the specified library.

Comment: Apparently he already links Gdi32.lib. As for coredll.lib, I am not sure but I think it should be there by default anyway, shouldn't it?

Comment: @j_kubik: He might *think* he's linking to Gdi32.lib and in reality be having an issue and not actually linking to it. Same for coredll.lib (which I too believe is default). Reality is though, that he wouldn't be getting these linker errors if he was actually properly linking to these libraries.

Comment: This is why I asked him for the actual linking command used - that should reveal what he is actually doing.

Comment: I can't see the whole command Eclipse uses; I added the path to the section with the -I option ("Libraries (-I)"). I tried it earlier with just the directory in the -L area ("Library search path (-L)"). I tried it with quotes, without quotes, and with/without escaped spaces where applicable.

Comment: I don't know Eclipse, but it would be quite user-unfriendly if it didn't allow you to see what it's actually doing underneath.

Comment: I would have despised the answer "don't use Eclipse / an IDE until you can compile/link things yourself", but AFAIK that was the answer I needed. Sorry I never posted the linking command Eclipse used, but I believe it was because I (thought I) had already screwed things up beyond the point where the troubleshooting would belong on a single SO question. Version control or even just restore points for project configuration could have saved me a lot of time. 
This question is getting a lot of views, so I'm back to mark best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, but i build using sublime text. 
So i came across with Sublime build system, i copy & paste the .json build from c++ .sublime-packages then i make new build system, 
 then i add -lgdi32 in the end of the line.

[image: -lgdi32]

and if i press F7 or Ctrl + B and works fine!

## Build json code

The code of the json looks like this!

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" -lgdi32",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" -lgdi32 && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the error `undefined reference` to functions defined in gdi32 but are already linking gdi32 then try moving gdi32 to the end of your linking commands.